# Javascript get SharePoint List items, enumerate, and locate and pin each item on Bing Map

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-online, office-365

The map is rendering and debugging in IEf12 does not show any error with loading the list.  I am using a CEWP referencing this file - SharePoint Online (Office 365). What's wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, infobox, dataLayer, listItems, listTitle;

    function getMap()
    {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
            credentials: 'MyBingMapsKey'
        });

        dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(dataLayer);

        var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

        infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { 
                    visible: false, 
                    offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 20) 
                });
        infoboxLayer.push(infobox);

        listTitle = getQueryStringValue('MapData');

        if(listTitle){
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadList,'sp.js');
        }
    }

    function loadList(){
        getListItems(listTitle);            
    }

    function getListItems(listTitle){
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var targetlist = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

        listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
        context.load(listItems);

        context.executeQueryAsync(onLoadItemsSuccess, onLoadItemsFail);
    }

    function onLoadItemsFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get lists items. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

    function onLoadItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
        var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

        var item, pin, loc;
        while (listEnumerator.moveNext())  {
            item = listEnumerator.get_current();
            loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(item.get_item('Latitude'), item.get_item('Longitude'));
            pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
            pin.Metadata = {
                Title : item.get_item('Title'),
                Location : item.get_item('City')
            };
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
            map.entities.push(pin); 

        }
    }

    function displayInfobox(e) {
        if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
            infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
            infobox.setOptions({ 
                visible: true, 
                title: e.target.Metadata.Title, 
                description: e.target.Metadata.Location 
            });
        }
    } 

    function getQueryStringValue(key) {
        var queryString = document.URL.split("?");
        if(queryString && queryString.length > 1)
        {
            var params = queryString[1].split("&");

            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                var value = params[i].split("=");
                if (value[0] == key){
                    return value[1];
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
onload = getMap;

</script>
<div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:900px; height:600px;"></div> 
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any items from list? Do they have proper coordinates? Are coordinates in correct format (50.0000 vs. 50°4'11.341"N)?

Comment: luccio .. I am not getting any results .. the coordinates are decimal degrees NOT Degree, Minute, Second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Page load in SharePoint

   For SharePoint pages you can’t directly add a function to the body’s
   onload event ([more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/22/javascript-pageload-add-function.aspx))

   So, this line

   ```
   onload = getMap;
   ```

   should be replaced to this one:

   ```
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getMap");
   ```
2. Referencing undefined object `targetList` (typo error)

   In line

   ```
   listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
   ```

   there is the reference to `targetList`, which is always returns undefined value.

   So, I believe it should be like this:

   ```
   listItems = targetlist.getItems(query);
   ```

---

### How to load Bing Map using CEWP

In order to load Bing Map for the code sample presented [here](http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/03/26/connecting-a-sharepoint-list-to-bing-maps.aspx) follow these steps:

1. Create Custom List and add the following new fields to the List:

   Latitude (Number), Longitude (Number), City (Note)
2. Save JavaScript ([source](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5327253)) and Html([source](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/5327246)) code for maps into separate files and place
   them, for example in Documents library
3. In CEWP specify path to Html file using [Content Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.contentlink.aspx) property,
   for example `/Geo/Shared Documents/NokiaStoresMap.htm`

> Note: For some reason function `loadList` is never being executed in
>   my case. The workaround was to load explicitly SP.js, so the line
>
> ```
> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadList,'sp.js');
> ```
>
> should be replaced with this one:
>
> ```
> LoadSodByKey('sp.js')
> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadList,'sp.js');
> ```

### Usage

The list title should be passed via url, for example to display information from list titled NokiaStores the following url is used:

```
/Geo/Pages/Default.aspx?MapData=NokiaStores
```

Comment: Thank you, Vadim. The pushpin's are still not rendering, Map runs fine - something with accessing and load the list isn't right.  I based this solution from recent bing blog http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/03/26/connecting-a-sharepoint-list-to-bing-maps.aspx - which does not work inside a page viewer web part.  I modified to a .js and edited the script.

Comment: Greg, the answer has been updated with information about usage of specified code sample with CEWP.

Comment: Vadim, Thank you!  I don't understand passed via url - do you customize the URL of the page the CEWP is part of to get this functionality?

Comment: Greg, exactly, list title is retrieved from query string and therefore it  should be appended for the page where CEWP is hosted: ?MapData={ListTitle}

Comment: Worked!!!! You rock, Vadim! Thankyou so much!

Comment: Greg, glad to hear it :)